# Do you look at how big your variables get and then choose the datatype accordingly to be more efficient?

Tags: c

This may sound like a strange question, but I am curious.  If you want to make your code as efficient as possible, would this be something common for people to do?  For example, you could use short datatypes instead of the int datatypes to do your processing.  Or is it usually the case that the efficiency is much less than the time used to do efficient coding?

Thanks...

Comment: Using a short instead of an int will almost certainly be slower.

Comment: Why would using a short be slower than an int?  16 bit vs 32 bit? Thanks~

Comment: generally short needs to be promoted to int to do the calculation, the demoted back to a short.   It takes more machine instructions

Comment: @EvilTeach, do you know any link to see such details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most machines int is faster than short/char, so there's not much to think about there. Always use int unless you need 64-bit integers. Or maybe if you really need to save memory then the smaller types might be useful.

Between float and double, I think it's better to default on double, just because the accuracy on float is pretty bad for any sort of numerical calculations. Only if you really need the extra performance and don't care about accuracy then use float.

Answer (score 3):

You should *never* use the types `short`, `char`, `float`, or similar except for making arrays. Otherwise, use `int`, `size_t`, `double`, or larger types as-needed.

Comment: Why should we never use short, char, float when not making arrays?  Never heard of this one before.

Comment: Types smaller than `int` have confusing semantics due to default promotions; `unsigned short` for example will get promoted to the *signed* type `int`, and `x+1` can fall outside the range of values for the type of `x` if `x` is smaller-than-`int`. `short` also tends to be slow on certain generations of x86 and likely even slower on some RISC machines that don't even have 16-bit load/store operations.

Comment: Also note `x+1` and `x+=1` can have different values if `x` is smaller than `int`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a struct that will have a lot of instances in the program, then I'm more careful to choose appropriately sized types in order to save some memory.

But using a `char` instead of an `int` as a function parameter just because you suppose that the range will be small is a bit silly IMO.

Answer (score 1):

No not really, unless you have memory restrictions, there is no reason to prematurely reduce the size of your types.

Places where you would be careful though is using large types in long arrays for example, or large structs (ie: has many members) that are used often.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a resource limited platform, such as embedded system, it may be valuable and sometimes even necessary to choose a short or a `char` rather than an `int` to conserve memory.  Otherwise, stick with the `int` and `double` data types.

Answer (score 0):

I just use ints and doubles by default unless they are in a time critical part of the code, then I am more careful in chosing